# Is there other ways to convert a string to int in python2 without int and string.atoi?

Tags: string, python-2.7, int

Is there other ways to convert a string to int in python2 without int and string.atoi? Like convert a "2" to 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a="2"
>>> int(a)
2
>>>
```

I would recommend using try catch,

```
try:
   a = int(a)
except:
   #do something
```

You can also use `ast` module,

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("2")
2
>>>
```

Comment: I know the int() and string.atoi(). But don't know the ast.literal_eval yet, seems eval() can also do this, thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a more "esoteric" solution like this!

```
def ascii_to_int(number):   
    value = 0
    multiplier = 1
    for n in reversed(number):
        value += (ord(n)-48)*multiplier
        multiplier *= 10
    return value


result_value = ascii_to_int('123')

print result_value, type(result_value)
```

the output is

```
123 <type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert string to Int without any standard function (using an algorithm)... just follow this little tutorial : [www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIJ289o6hxY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIJ289o6hxY)

Comment: From the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.